# Difficulty in constructing Luhn's algorithm

Tags: javascript

I want to construct Luhn's algorithm which is usually used to validate credit card numbers. Luhn's algorithm works like this:

- Isolate every digit, starting from the right moving left, doubling every second one. If the doubled value is greater than 9, subtract 9 from it.
- Sum all the transformed digits.
- The original number valid according to Luhn's algorithm if and only if the sum ends in a 0.

```
    function isValid(number) {
      return LuhnDigitSum(number) % 10 === 0;
    }

    function LuhnDigitSum(number) {
      let sum = 0;
      let num_str = number.toString();
      let reversed_num = num_str.split("").reverse().join("");
      for (let i = 0; i < reversed_num.length; i++) {
        let digit = parseInt(reversed_num[i]);
        if (i % 2 !== 0 && (digit * 2) <= 9) {
          digit = digit * 2;
          sum += digit;
        }
        if (i % 2 !== 0 && (digit * 2) > 9) {
          digit = (digit * 2) - 9;
          sum += digit;
        }
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          sum += digit;
        }
      }
      return sum;
    }
```

When i run the code, the card numbers appeared to be invalid when they are supposed to be valid, and adding to that, the sum value were incorrect.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Please show us what you tried, resp. give us a proper description of what part of the problem you are not able to solve on your own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't describe any specific issue, the OP just asks for somebody else to write the code for them.

Comment: Simply *Google* **search**: `github Luhn's algorithm javascript`? - [here](https://github.com/bendrucker/fast-luhn), [here](https://gist.github.com/DiegoSalazar/4075533).

Comment: Have you tried something? Post your code.

Comment: Your requirements do not really fit. If you always increase `sum`, it'll never be 0 ...

Comment: @Jonas Wilms Thanks a lot! I've managed to solve it with "else if" statement.

Comment: You can find more info here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/luhn-algorithm/